# What is the correct syntax for combining and with an OR statement

Tags: sql, syntax

Can anyone assist with this syntax?  I am receiving error messages

```
and ((a.admit_date between @period1_claim_start and @period1_claim_end and a.paid_date <= @period1_paid_date)
        or (a.admit_date between @period2_claim_start and @period2_claim_end and a.paid_date <= @period2_paid_date))
        and a.SVC_TYP_DESC <>'BH' --!! IS THAT OKAY TO REMOVE BH FROM INPATIENT???
        and ((e.EFFPER between @period1_claim_start and @period1_claim_end 
        or (e.effper between @period2_claim_Start and @period2_claim_end))
```

Comment: What is the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Removed unnecessary parentheses:

```
and 
(
    (a.admit_date between @period1_claim_start and @period1_claim_end and a.paid_date <= @period1_paid_date) 
    or 
    (a.admit_date between @period2_claim_start and @period2_claim_end and a.paid_date <= @period2_paid_date)
) 
and 
    a.SVC_TYP_DESC <>'BH' 
and 
(
    e.EFFPER between @period1_claim_start and @period1_claim_end 
    or 
    e.effper between @period2_claim_Start and @period2_claim_end
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you are missing one a final closure in your statement

you have 6 ( and 5 )

Adjustment:

and (
 (a.admit_date between @period1_claim_start and @period1_claim_end and a.paid_date <= @period1_paid_date) 
  or 
 (a.admit_date between @period2_claim_start and @period2_claim_end and a.paid_date <= @period2_paid_date)
)

and a.SVC_TYP_DESC <>'BH' 
--!! IS THAT OKAY TO REMOVE BH FROM INPATIENT???

and (
 (e.EFFPER between @period1_claim_start and @period1_claim_end 
   or (e.effper between @period2_claim_Start and @period2_claim_end)
 )
)

but past that we have no idea what any additional error messages you have unless you tell us.

It also near impossible for us to tell you what parenthesis are valid and not because we do not know your business case.